# Prove without induction: Eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-independence

Prove that if $\{b_n\}$ are eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_n\}$, then $\{b_n\}$ are linearly independent.

*Note: Proofs for this are available on this site and elsewhere.  My question is to verify* my *proof below, which, at least to me, is simpler.*

**Lemma:** If $B$ is a finite set of linear independent vectors, there is at most one linear combination of $B$ equal to a given vector $v$.

**Proof:** Consider a finite set $\{b_n\}$ of linearly independent vectors.  Assume $\sum_n c_nb_n = v$ and $\sum_n c'_nb_n = v$, with at least one $c_n \neq c'_n$.  Then $\sum_n (c_n - c'_n)b_n = v - v = 0$, which is impossible since $\{b_n\}$ is linearly independent.

**Main Proof:** Let $\{b_n\}$ be linearly independent eigenvectors of matrix $A$ with distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_n\}$.  Let $d$ be a distinct eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\delta \notin \{\lambda_n\}$.  We claim that $d$ is linearly independent of $\{b_n\}$.

Assume $d$ is *not* linearly independent of $\{b_n\}$.  Then there exists $\{c_n\}$ such that $\sum_n c_nb_n = d$.  Consequently, $Ad = \sum_n \lambda_n c_n b_n$.  But $Ad = \delta d = \sum_n \delta c_n b_n$.  This would give two different linear combinations of $\{b_n\}$ that yield $Ad$, violating the lemma.  Hence, $d$ must be linearly independent of $\{b_n\}$.

**Questions:** Is this proof correct, rigorous, and well written? How can it be improved?

As far as I can tell, this proof does not use induction.  Is that correct?

---

### Update

*Thank you the responders.  I believe I need to add the following step, which indeed uses induction.  Can you please verify that with this step, the proof is correct?*

Let $B_0$ be the empty set, and for all $n \in \mathbb N$, let $B_n = B_{n-1} \cup \{b_n\}$.  If $B_n$ is a set (possibly empty) of linearly independent eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues, $B_{n+1}$ must also be, as proven above.  $B_0$ is such a set, and so therefore $B_n$ is such for all $n$.  This completes the proof.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a proof without induction? That sure looks like an inductive step.

Comment: @eyeballfrog - Yes, I'd say they had done the inductive step, and left out the base case, and the words "the proof is by induction". I also think that the subtle distinction between "one vector is lin indep from a set of vectors" and "a lin indep set of vectors" makes it harder to see in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please review the fix.

Comment: You are missing at least one step: from $\sum \lambda_n c_nb_n = \sum \delta c_nb_n$, you should conclude that $\lambda_n c_n=\delta c_n$ for all $n$. From the fact that $d$ is an eigenvector, and therefore not equal to zero, you know that at least on $c_i$ is nonzero. Then $\lambda_i c_i = \delta c_i$, and now you can cancel the $c_i$ to conclude that $\lambda_i=\delta$, contradicting the assumption that $\delta$ was distinct from all $\lambda_i$.

Comment: There is a theorem (proven by induction) that says that if $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ is a list of vectors, then it is linearly dependent if and only if there exists a $j$, $1\leq j\leq n$, such that $b_1,\ldots,b_{j-1}$ is linearly independent, and $b_j\in\mathrm{span}(b_1,\ldots,b_{j-1})$  You can then start with a list $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ of eigenvectors of pairwise distinct eigenvalues; if they are linearly independent, you are done. If not, then $n\gt 1$, and there pick $b_j$ as above and do your argument (with the added step). But this uses induction hidden in the minimality of $j$.